# MYSQL Foreign Key Set

Tags: mysql, set, foreign-keys

Abstract: Table A has a row which contains a list of Integers that reference IDs in Table B.

Why not just create a column in table B that references Table A? Because the items in Table B are reusable, and apply to many rows in table A.

Specific example: An educational software, which consists of lessons and line items. Each lesson incorporates many line items, and each line item is used in many lessons.

This many-to-many linking is a common task and I have probably been doing it wrong forever. The easiest way I have done it in the past is to have Table A contain a varchar with a delimited list, interpret that list in code and then run another query to get the needed information from table B.

Is there more elegant way? Some way of combining the functionality of SET data type with Foreign Keys index?

Answer (score 0):

For a Many to Many relationship you will be using 3 tables:

**Table** `Lesson`:
Columns: `ln_id`, `ln_lesson_name`

**Table** `LineItem`
Columns: `li_id`, `li_line_detail`

**And a relation table** `LineOfLesson`
Columns: `ls_lesson_id` (references the id in the Lesson table), `ls_line_item_id` (references the id in the LineItem table)

In this way by querying the three tables you can get either the lessons where a particular line is used or the lines that make up a particular lesson.

Side note: In the relation table the two ids together would be the natural primary key of the table.

Also if there were aditional information regarding the relation it would also be added here for example, you could add when was the line item was added.

Comment: Ok so there would then be many rows in the relation table to describe the lesson?   

IE: Line items 4, 5, and 6 are parts of lesson 1, so we have three rows in table AB?  

1 : 4   
1 : 5  
1 : 6  

It seems inelegant on the surface, but I do believe it is more efficient than two queries and regex. I had a feeling there was some basic vocabulary I was missing: relation table.  
  
I don't quite grasp what you mean by the two ID's together being the primary key.  
  
Thanks!

Comment: It actually is far more efficient than the approach you mention, as a start you are not limited to the size of varchar field. The database builds indexes on the ids so lookups are really quick, and you can even build more elaborate queries for example:  which are the lessons that mention 'bird' and 'lion' in any of its lines. I sugest you search on Relational Data Bases and Data Base Normalization.

Comment: efficient yes I'm sure. The main advantage to the previous way I was doing this was convenience, especially with updating sequence data, as in the relation table method many rows will have to be updated to change sequence... though I'm sure there is a 'normalized' way of handling this as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is accomplished with a relationship table.

**A** is one to one with **B**

- *A or B should contain the id of the other.*

**A** is one to many with **B**

- *B should contain the id of A.*

**A** is many to many with **B**

- *Create a relationship table AB that holds ids for both A and B.*

These are standard patterns.